# Merge (concatenate) two or more trees, by appending them, preserving their respective internal structure

Tags: python, merge, tree

I am working with Python. 
I have two trees, with a different structure (number and order of nodes).

I want to merge them and the respective root of each of the two starting trees, should become the first children list of the new root.

I am having hard times in achieving this. I am sure there must be a very trivial and easy way to do it, I am just overseeing it, I am sure.

Thank you

M.

Comment: Are you working with XML? What module are you using? Please provide more detail, and perhaps a snippet of code to have an idea of what your structure looks like / what you want it to look like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an adjacency list representation, it should be easy to do so :

- Create a new tree made of only one vertex
- Add your previous trees as children of the new vertex

Of course, it highly depends on the type of structure you use and you it is implemented.

If you are interested, I suggest you to have a look at the `treex` library that I contributed to develop, that is meant to process trees, inherited data structures and various algorithms. You can find the library here : https://gitlab.inria.fr/azais/treex

As an exemple, in `treex`, what you wish to do (if I understood right) should be done like this :

```
t = Tree()
t.add_subtree(t1) #your first tree to merge
t.add_subtree(t2) #the second one, and so on
```